# Start scrollbar at the left for Highstock

Tags: highcharts

I need to start the scrollbar at the left instead of the right for my Highstock graph. Any suggestions? I've seen the setExtremes options but I'm either not using it right or it doesn't do what I need. Here is the code for the graph I have so far.

```
$(function() {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Placed By Advisor'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['John Jenkins', 'Steve Smith', 'Will Douglas', 'Dustin Johnson', 'Suzy Abbott', 'Wendy Jones'],
        min: 2

    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0
    },
    legend: {
        shadow: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0.5
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Unemployed',
        data: [100, 100, 120, 55, 35, 189]},
    {
        name: 'Placed In Related',
        data: [80, 108, 15, 74, 48, 88]},
    {
        name: 'Placed In Unrelated',
        data: [17, 22, 187, 70, 75, 35]},
    {
        name: 'Except',
        data: [10, 0, 19, 65, 25, 174]}],

    scrollbar: {
        enabled:true,
        barBackgroundColor: 'lightgray',
        //barBorderRadius: 7,
        //barBorderWidth: 0,
        //buttonBackgroundColor: 'gray',
        //buttonBorderWidth: 0,
        //buttonArrowColor: 'yellow',
        //buttonBorderRadius: 0,
        //rifleColor: 'yellow',
        //trackBackgroundColor: 'red',
        //trackBorderWidth: 1,
        //trackBorderColor: 'silver',
        //trackBorderRadius: 7
    }
});

$('#button').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(

    );
});
```

});

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lukelarsen/yHGS9/2/) of what I have so far.

Comment: You can pass categories index to `setExtremes`. Like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/yHGS9/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `min` value as 0 and `max` as any (like 2).

http://jsfiddle.net/yHGS9/5/